# Error with running application in GWT development mode

Tags: java, gwt

There is a strange problem with my GWT development mode. Everything is fine with my project.The project also runs well while running using tomcat but when I run the project in GWT dev mode, the different kinds of error occurs in my console.

The most strange thing is that the error displayed is not same all the time.It throws different exception every time I run the project.Also, sometimes magically my project works fine even in GWT dev mode.I am suffering from this problem since long period of time.Please! can anyone help me to sort the problem.

The different kinds of error are:

```
    [ERROR] [projectName] - Exception initializing module
    [ERROR] [projectName] - Failed to load module 'projectName' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36' at localhost:46087
```

And sometimes

```
   # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
   #
   # SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd895353fd5, pid=7445, tid=140568325068544
   #
   # JRE version: 6.0_45-b06
   # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.45-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64    compressed oops)
   # Problematic frame:
   # J  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findMemberType([CLorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ReferenceBinding;)Lorg/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/ReferenceBinding;
   #
   # An error report file with more information is saved as:
   # /home/pushpa/esewa-default/esewa-hg/esewa-server/hs_err_pid7445.log
   #
   # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
   #   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Please! help me to sort out the problem

Comment: Looks linke the jvm crashs. Is the installed JVM in tomcat and in dev mode the same?

Comment: @Jens Can you please say how can I check which JVM is installed in GWT dev mode.Thankyou!